# How to run a Python Script with imports from Deno?

Tags: javascript, python, deno

I am currently trying to run a python file from a deno backend using the following code...

```
const cmd = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["python", "python.py"], 
    stdout: "piped",
    stderr: "piped"
});

const output = await cmd.output() // "piped" must be set
const outStr = new TextDecoder().decode(output);

const error = await cmd.stderrOutput();
const errorStr = new TextDecoder().decode(error);

cmd.close(); 
console.log(outStr, errorStr);

const resultsAlgorithm = outStr
console.log('This is a test, python result is...',outStr)
console.log('Finished')
```

The code works for basic scripts like 'print("Hello")' but is unable to run imports on more complex scripts such as...

```
   import pandas as pd  # Changes call up name to pd
   from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
   from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta,time

   Yahoo_Forex = pd.DataFrame()
   Currency_Pair_Prices = pd.DataFrame()

   print('Running')


    def DataExtract(FileName, DataFrameName, DataFrameName_2, time_range, Interval, ColumnName):
        print('Function started')
        start = date.today() - timedelta(days=2)  
        end = date.today() - timedelta(days=time_range)  
        DataFrameName = pd.read_excel(FileName, header=None)  
        DataFrameName.columns = ColumnName  
        n = 0  
        for ticker in DataFrameName[ColumnName[0]]:  
            Currency_Pair = DataFrameName.iloc[n, 1]  
            Currency_Pair_Ticker = YahooFinancials(ticker)  
            data = Currency_Pair_Ticker.get_historical_price_data(
                str(end), str(start), Interval) 
            Extracted_Data = pd.DataFrame(data[ticker]["prices"])  
            Currency_Close_Price = (Extracted_Data["close"])  
            DataFrameName_2[str(Currency_Pair)] = Currency_Close_Price  
            n = n+1  # 13
        print(DataFrameName_2)
        print("DataExtract Completed")
    
    
    DataExtract("yahoo_Forex.xlsx", Yahoo_Forex, Currency_Pair_Prices,int(10), "daily", ["Ticker", "Pair", "Exchange"])
```

The python code runs successfully on it's own so must be something with deno but sure what I would need to change so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem actually is. What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: The program is unable to read the imports and produces an error code "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yahoofinancials'" . All imports and modules work when the python file is run 
separately.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing more about your setup but Python modules can be installed in different environments, even virtual environments. When you run it directly yourself I suspect it uses one environment where you've used pip and installed your modules while `Deno.run` uses a different environment (you'd probably get the same result through Node, Go, or any other language calling out). I think this is more of a Python issue than a Deno issue. I suggest confirming they use different environments and learning why and then you should be able to determine next steps from there.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that side of things! Appreciate the help

Comment: @mfulton26  I reinstalled the modules in the project folder and that solved the errors, thanks for the help!